# touchstart stopped working into iOS8

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I have a HTML game that has left and right buttons when the user plays on a mobile. It all was working fine until iOS8 came out. Now the buttons seem really unresponsive. I have been using touchstart and touch end to detect when a user is holding down a button:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });

        btnLeft.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
            dir = "left";
            player.isKeyDown = true;
            player.isMovingLeft = true;
        }, false);

        btnLeft.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
            player.isKeyDown = false;
            player.isMovingLeft = false;
        }, false);

        btnRight.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
            player.isKeyDown = true;
            player.isMovingRight = true;
            dir = "right";
        }, false);

        btnRight.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
            player.isKeyDown = false;
            player.isMovingRight = false;
        }, false);
```

Comment: SOLVED. It was scrollToY causing the issue.